# How to tell quantitatively whether 1D data is clustered around 1 or 3 values?

Tags: clustering

I've got some data on the time between heart beats of a human. One indication of ectopic (extra) beats is that these intervals are clustered around three values instead of one. How can I obtain a quantitative measure of this?

I'm looking to compare multiple data sets, and these two 100-bin histograms are representative of all of them.

[image]

I could compare the variances, but I want my algorithm to be able to detect whether there is one or three clusters in each case without comparing to the other cases.

This is for offline processing, so there's a lot of computation power available, if that's needed.

Comment: **Related**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5960/how-to-identify-a-bimodal-distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise strongly *against* using k-means here. The results for different values of k aren't very well comparable. The method is just a crude heuristic. If you really want to use clustering, use EM clustering, since your data seems to contain normal distributions. And validate your results!

Instead, the obvious approach is to try fitting a single Gaussian function and (for example using the Levenberg-Marquard method) fit three Gaussian functions, maybe constrained to the same height (to avoid degeneration).

Then test, which of the two distributions fits better.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of Levenberg-Marquardt! These clusters are not Gaussian; do you still think Gaussian functions would be the best PDF to fit them to?

Comment: +1 to this and to Greg Snow. I totally agree with this advice. @Nikolaus I think this looks "gaussian enough" to fit a mixture of gaussians distributions. You don’t want a perfect fit, just a way to check how many clusters there are. In this optic, constraining all components to share the same standard deviation can be a good idea (for the reasons explained by Anony-Mousse).

Comment: They clearly look Gaussian enough to me. K-means models data with Voronoi cells. It does not seem sensible to me to assume that the best split point is exactly in the middle of the two neighboring means.

Answer (score 6):

Fit a mixture distribution to the data, something like a mixture of 3 normal distributions, then compare the likelihood of that fit to a fit of a single normal distribution (using likelihood ratio test, or AIC/BIC).  The `flexmix` package for `R` may be of help.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use K-means clustering, then you need a way to compare the $K=1$ and $K=3$ cases. One approach would be to use the [gap statistic](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/gap.ps&ei=_-byTqWjEqWlsQK3vc3VAQ&usg=AFQjCNF9sG6CbcPIxnDLxmLoxaypuaH0uQ) from Tibshirani et al. and choose the $K$ that provides the better value. There's an R implementation available in [SLmisc](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/SLmisc/html/kmeansGap.html), though that particular function will try $K=1,2,3$, so you will need to take care to ensure that only $K=1$ or $K=3$ can be returned as the optimal value.

Answer (score 3):

Use a K-means clustering algorithm to identify the various means

Look for function KNN in R-seek to find the appropriate function

Comment: ahh, I was just about to post that! You can also refer to this link for the codes and whatnots: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html

Comment: I tried with Matlab's `kmeans` function. The resulting means vary widely from try to try. (Bad heuristics in this implementation?) For the 1-cluster set, I get means around (270,293,693) sometimes, around (260,285,308) sometimes. For the 3-cluster set, some answers are (196,324,468,) and (290,459,478).

Comment: Is there a place where I can paste the data?

Comment: Oh, about that 693 mean: there are two obvious outliers, a 532 and an 855, out of a total 755 values. All the rest of the values can be seen in the histogram.

Comment: You must look beyond the means you get from k-means, and see how well they actually describe your data!