# Generic test for unimodality given sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, normal-distribution, t-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Are there any generic tests to validate if a given sample follows a unimodal distribution, like a Gaussian, Cauchy, Student's t or a chi-square?

Comment: Note that you may think of the Unimodal distribution as a "family" of distributions. The common characteristic is that there is one *mode*. A mode has the property that its probability density is equal to the maximum density of the pdf, while at every direction away from the mode the density is *non-increasing*. Under this definition, all the distributions you mention fall under the unimodal category: *Gaussian, Cauchy, Student's t* or a *Chi-square*. In addition, the *Uniform* distribution is also unimodal. In fact, Uniform is the distribution that Hartigan and Hartigan have used in the [pape

Comment: I wouldn't say the uniform was unimodal. It doesn't satisfy your definition.

Comment: @argyris: You migh have got me wrong: I recalled these distributions as an example for unimodal ones.

Comment: @NickCox: You're right, but Hartigan's test returns a p>0.2 for uniform distributions of sample size > 500. Thus, there is a high risk of judging them to be non-multimodal, although they are in fact considered unimodal.

Comment: I don't understand your "but" here. Does "non-multimodal" mean anything but "unimodal"? The Hartigan-Hartigan test [let's not forget that it's two of them, husband and wife] treats the uniform as reference as in a sense the worst case unimodal. @argyris' definition doesn't seem to match that.

Comment: @NickCox: I can hardly accept a uniform as actually "unimodal", if it's more a case of many modes of the same density. Nevertheless, I might be able to accept it as "the worst case unimodal", as you described it. In this case, Hartigans p-Value also makes some sense.

Comment: I am not sure what hinges on your acceptance here. Your first sentence echoes my first point. My "worst case unimodal" was a paraphrase of the Hartigan-Hartigan approach; their Abstract alone gives a more formal wording.

Comment: There are numerous tests for unimodality (I think I once identified about nine). I think the dip test is the most well-known.  (Edit:  [yep - it is nine if you include the Donoho test mentioned at the end](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51062/test-for-bimodal-distribution/51085#51085))

Comment: NB for anyone considering this a duplicate on the basis of the above link - I would lean toward not marking this question as a duplicate, because even though that answer applies here, the question there is different - the bimodal alternative in the question there is not the same as the 'not unimodal' alternative in the question here.

Comment: @Glen_b: and particular, Hartigans' test is the one implemented in R! :-)

Comment: @Chris I mention which package it's in at the linked answer above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're asking two questions:

1. Is there a generic test for unimodality?
2. Are there tests to test whether a sample is derived from a given distribution, say, a normal distribution?

Ad 1): Yes, the Hartigan-Hartigan dip test, [Ann. Statist. 13(1):70-84](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-13/issue-1/The-Dip-Test-of-Unimodality/10.1214/aos/1176346577.full).

Ad 2): There exists a number of special tests, but the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test is a general-purpose nonparametric test, although with low statistical power.