# Testing for Unimodality or Bimodality Data Using MATLAB

Tags: distributions, matlab, aic, gaussian-mixture-distribution, kernel-smoothing

I am trying to figure out what I did wrong or what I could do to get accurate results.

I have *n* vectors of data, and I am trying to decide whether each dataset is unimodal or bimodal.  I assumed that it could be a mixture of Gaussians, so in MATLAB I attempted:

```
fit1 = gmdistribution(data(:,x),1)  %x is the index for each vector
fit2 = gmdistribution(data(:,x),2)
```

I used the minimum AIC of the two to decide whether it is unimodal or bimodal. The results return all to be bimodal, but they all aren't.  Also by looking at the histograms of the data, they all don't seem bimodal.  My question is why am I getting inaccurate or false positive results? Is there a better method? Did I do something wrong?

SOME EDITS:

using the gmdistribution function and the mean and variance from fit1 and fit2, I created random samples using:

```
Y = random(obj,length(original_data) %obj contains unimodal dist.
Y2 = random(obj2, length(original_data) %obj2 contains bimodal
hist(Y, length(original_data)
hist(Y2, length(original_data)
```

I compared each to the original vectors of data and the bimodal seems to provide samples that most resembles the original data.  Is this a proper way of testing the AIC or dip test?   I also used the hartigans dip test in matlab and the p values were close to 0 (less than 0.05), so I assumed this also means bimodal.  I checked the kurtosis also, but they didn't return all bimodal. Any inputs or direction?

Comment: how large is your sample size?

Comment: The sample size of the vectors range from 867 samples to 1821

Comment: With a thousand or more data points, even fairly subtle wiggles can be detected as modes. If this seems wrong to you, hypothesis testing is the wrong tool for your problem.

Comment: 1. Checking the kurtosis to check the presence of bimodality can be quite tricky; probably a $strong$ negative number might indicate that but still it would be a stretch to be simply based on this. Kurtosis is sensitive to outliers so be weary. 2. Using two distribution will almost certainly give you `samples that most resemble(s) the original data` in comparison with a single distribution so that does not say much. 3. Check the following thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95015/is-it-valid-to-use-hartigans-dip-test-to-reject-uni-modal-null-hypothesis-with it will probably help.

Answer (score 3):

Three points:

1. You are talking about floating point variables; therefore the comparison `fit1.AIC == fit2.AIC` is very unlikely to ever happen. Check the concept of [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Approximation_using_MATLAB). Probably you want something in line of: `abs(fit1.AIC - fit2.AIC) < 2*eps` to test equality.
2. Usually an AIC difference equal or less than 2 is practically a tie as in this case the relative Akaike weight are quite inconclusive. AIC should not be used in absolute terms. Some useful informal references: [[1](http://myweb.uiowa.edu/cavaaugh/ms_lec_14_ho.pdf),[2](http://warnercnr.colostate.edu/~anderson/PDF_files/AIC%20Myths%20and%20Misunderstandings.pdf),[3](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~shu3/Presentation/AIC.pdf)], and two real ones: [Burnham and Anderson, 2002](https://encrypted.google.com/books?id=BQYR6js0CC8C) and [Posada and Buckley, 2004](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4135365?uid=3738032&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104486011033).
3. I suspect that what might happen is that probably you are using a mixture of two Gaussian with $\mu$'s that are relatively close but std. deviations $\sigma$'s that are quite different. In that way your second distribution can account for some outliers in your sample. Without the actual data and/or at least the outputs of `fit1` and `fit2` one can only make guesses.

Comment: My pleasure; if you add an example `fit1` & `fit2` I might be able to help more. :)

Comment: I haven't added an example but I added edits of what I did further.  If you could comment on that I would appreciate it.  I am trying to get a sense of if I am headed in the right direction.  Thanks again

Comment: Sorry I can't make up much of this extra information. The wikipedia article on bimodal distributions list quite a few test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimodal_distribution#Statistical_tests maybe bootstraping is something you would like also explore (eg. see $Silverman's test$). Just to clarify: what is $\Delta$AIC between `fit1` and `fit2`?

Comment: fit1.AIC-fit2.AIC of the datasets range from 59 to over 2000 over.

Comment: In general without seeing at least a KDE of the data I would extremely hesitant to draw conclusions, but realistically speaking some of those $\Delta$AIC values are very large especially for a dataset with less than 2000 points... Probably you do have a mixture of Gaussian after all. :) Check Silverman's test, if that also indicates a bimodal I would probably call it case closed.

Comment: Thanks again. This will be my last follow up - When you say KDE, I am assuming kernel density estimation.  When I run ksdensity to estimate the dist., what should I specifically look for? Just how the plot looks?  For Silverman's test, I don't have the matlab code so I don't think I will be trying that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The gmdistribution has AIC or BIC as elements of the goodness-of-fit structure.  If you look in the help documentation you can see it.

for the exact same data, it helps with selection of best analytic for to both allow generalization and minimize error.  Determining whether it is more likely bimodal or unimodal is what the measure was built for.

Link:

- http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution-class.html
- [http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/718/NonParametrics15.pdf](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/718/NonParametrics15.pdf)