# Index of Dispersion - How to test its significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, simulation, dispersion, underdispersion

Starting from [Poisson distribution and cluster analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240039/poisson-distribution-and-cluster-analysis)

I am trying to find a statistical/empirical method in order to test if my Index of Dispersion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_dispersion) is significant or not. I am not a statistician so please forgive any possible mistake I made on the calculation.

Here my data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'Year Count
  1975   10
  1976   12
  1977    9
  1978   14
  1979   14
  1980   11
  1981    8
  1982    7
  1983   10
  1984    8
  1985   12
  1986    9
  1987   10
  1988    9
  1989   10
  1990    9
  1991   11
  1992   12
  1993    9
  1994   10
  1995    8
  1996   12
  1997   11
  1998   13
  1999    7
  2000   13
  2001   10
  2002    9
  2003    8
  2004   13
  2005   15
  2006   11
  2007   10
  2008   11
  2009    9
  2010   10
  2011    8
  2012   11
  2013   10
  2014    6, header = TRUE)
```

Therefore, my Index of Dispersio phi will be equal to:

```
phi = var(df$Count) / mean(df$Count)

> print(phi)
[1] 0.4137045
```

So my data show underdispersion because 0 < phi < 1

**How to test the significance of phi?**

I couldn't find any specific test therefore I tried with a simulation of 10,000 random vectors created from a uniform distribution (i.e. each observation with same probability to occur).

Here my 'test' code:

```
#create list
list = lapply(1:10000, function(x) x = data.frame(round(runif(409, 1975, 2014)))) #409 is the total number of observations for each vector and is equal to sum(df$Count)

#count how many observations per year
list_tbl = lapply(list, function(y) y = data.frame(table(y$round.runif.409..1975..2014..)))

#calculate the index of dispersion for each vector
list_phi = lapply(list_tbl, function(z) z = var(z$Freq) / mean(z$Freq))

#unlist in order to have all the indexes in one df
sim_phi = unlist(list_phi)

#hist of indexes
hist(sim_phi)

#print mean, standard deviation and variance
> mean(sim_phi)
[1] 1.129969
> sd(sim_phi)
[1] 0.2422462
> var(sim_phi)
[1] 0.05868323
```

Can I affirm that my `phi = 0.4137045` is not significant because the simulation pointed out `mean(sim_phi) = 1.129969` showing then overdispersion?

Comment: Significant in what sense?

Comment: p-values. significant in the sense to check if my VMR index has came out by chance or not.

Comment: This question seems perhaps related to [this recent question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240039/poisson-distribution-and-cluster-analysis). If this is the same user (?), then you should mention the context by linking to that question (and [merge accounts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)).

Comment: Based on the results of the simulation, wouldn't a test of whether or not the simulated mean is significantly different from zero answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your first link, [Index of Dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_dispersion#Statistics), under the "Statistics" section, it says (see Wikipedia link for definitions)

> If the variates are Poisson distributed then the index of dispersion is distributed as a $\chi^2$ statistic with $n-1$ degrees of freedom when $n$ is large and $μ>3$. For many cases of interest this approximation is accurate and Fisher in 1950 derived an exact test for it.

and gives a citation for the relevant paper

> Frome, E. L. (1982). [Algorithm AS 171: Fisher's Exact Variance Test for the Poisson Distribution](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=12005425740670134023). Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series C (Applied Statistics), 31(1), 67-71.

This would seem to be the standard [significance test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-significance) relevant to your case, under the null hypothesis that your data are [i.i.d.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iid) Poisson.

---

In response to the comment: I do not use `R`, so I cannot say for sure (though [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactci/) may be it).

However, your data has $n=40$ and $\bar{x}=10.25\gg 3$, so the chi-squared approximation should be reasonable. Given your sample variance of $s^2=4.23$, then by the formula cited in the reference above, the statistic
$$t=\frac{s^2(n-1)}{\bar{x}}=16.23$$
should follow a chi-squared distribution with $n-1=39$ degrees of freedom, under the null hypothesis.

From the [chi-squared CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), under the null hypothesis you would then have $$\Pr[t\leq{16.23}]=4.5\times 10^{-4}$$
So you can reject the null hypothesis with a *very* high degree of certainty (your [p-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/p-value/info) is more than **two orders of magnitude smaller** than the "default" value of $5\times 10^{-2}$ given in the tag wiki). As noted in my answer to the [other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/240116/127790), this does *not* seem like a borderline case at all.

Comment: thanks! any chance to know if there exists an R package to perform the test? I searched a lot but I didn't find anything

Comment: @no_one I updated the question. To all, I *think* my significance-test example is correct (numbers and *terminology*), but as I am not much of a statistician, corrections welcomed!

Comment: thanks @GeoMatt22. you found what I was looking for. however, regarding the test formula, I think is not correct. if you have a look at http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1015126322223 equation (1) seems the one proposed by Fisher 1950.

Comment: no, sorry. please ignore my comment :)

Comment: by the way, I don't understand how you created the formula (from the reference) and how you calculated the p-value. sorry..

Comment: I took the formula from first 3 sentences of ref, [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2347079). The CDF formula is on the top right "PDF facts" box on the Wikipedia page (I used `gammainc()` in Matlab).