Is there a statistic to describe 'clumpiness' in a scatterplot?
I've produced the following scatterplot showing the predictions of a variable (y-axis) against the "true" value (x-axis). I've used two different machine learning methods -- k-Nearest Neighbours (kNN) and a neural network (NN) -- and the scatterplot for the NN seems to have two clumps in it; one centered around $z_\mathrm{spec} \sim 1.25$ and the other around $z_\mathrm{spec} \sim 2$.
My question is: is there a way to quantify this clumpiness, or a statistic I could use to compare the two scatterplots?
Most of the sources I've seen, such as this question and this article talk about clumpiness in network graphs, but that's not what I'm after.


This seems relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5960/how-to-identify-a-bimodal-distribution

Consider the log likelihood ratio for comparing a unimodal fit to a two-component mixture.  With so much data available the conclusion will be fairly insensitive to the shapes of the components, provided you allow for general affine transformations to accommodate their orientations, sizes, and aspect ratios.
